# NFA to accept strings where the third AND the third-last element are b

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Alphabet is {a,b}, the third element from the start must be "b" (e.g: aab..., abb...) and the third-last element must also be "b" (e.g: ...baa, ...bbb). I can do them separately but at the same time I don't know where to start. Help please.

Comment: If you can construct DFAs for both constraints separately you can easily build a DFA that accepts the intersection: http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/gordon.pace/Research/Software/Relic/Transformations/FSA/intersection.html 
or better: 
http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/portiz/SI340/classes/L03/L03_Complement_Intersection_Union_Machines.pdf

Comment: Does it only work for DFAs?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662041/how-to-find-the-intersection-of-two-nfa

Comment: But there are also intuitive algorithms to transform a NFA to a DFA: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/ndfa_to_dfa_conversion.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. If $A$ is the alphabet, a regular expression for your language is $AAbA^*bAA \cup AAbAA \cup AbbA \cup bAb$.

Comment: @G.Bach I wrote both my answer and in my answer to your comment in a hurry, but now that I have more time, I would like to thank you for pointing out my mistake in this elegant way.

Comment: Thank you! That's right, since the automaton is nondeterministic, I can just concatenate the three of them (bxb, xbbx and xxbxx), it works now.